# How to make child content of a node uneditable dynamically in ProseMirror?

Tags: javascript, prose-mirror

I have created a document schema that includes a `captioned_image` node type, which references an image in a separate CMS. The image has a caption and a credit, which I'd like editable in the document. When the user edits the content in the ProseMirror editor, I can take note of the change and send a request to the CMS with the updates.

However, the caption and credit fields can be "locked" when another user is editing the image in the CMS.

How can I make the caption and credit child nodes of the `captioned_image` node non-editable, when those fields are locked by another user? A selection shouldn't be able to be placed in a position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways

1. When a piece of the document is locked, filter transform actions, canceling (resetting to the old state) any that touch this region (can be determined by calling `forEach` on the elements in `action.transform.mapping.maps`).
2. Write a custom node view for these kinds of nodes, and give them an attribute `readOnly`. Toggle it when they should become uneditable, and when it is on, render the locked content with `contenteditable=false`. But note that this does not protect against programmatic changes to the content. Also, it will make it impossible to put the cursor into them, which might not be desired.